test the code inside OnAuthStateChange - jest
I'm doing tests for LoginScreen in my react native app using Jest , but I'm facing problem to test block of code inside onAuthStateChange method .
LoginScreen.tsx

  const setToken= async(token:any)=> {
  await SecureStore.setItemAsync('token', token)
   //setSkip(false)
}
useEffect(() => {
     const unsubscribe = auth().onAuthStateChanged( (user: FirebaseAuthTypes.User | null) => {
         console.log("USER IS STILL LOGGED IN: " , user);
         if (user) { current user
           user.getIdToken(true)
           .then(latestToken => {
             console.log(latestToken)
             console.log(user)
            setToken(latestToken) //call setToken function   
           setUserID(user.uid)    //state change 
           })
           .catch(err => console.log(err))
         }else {
           if user signed out from profile screen
           deleteToken()
         }
         return unsubscribe();
      });
  }, [isUerSignedIn]);   

mockFile  //mocks/@react-native-firebase/auth/index
 export const mockedUserCredentials={
             sendEmailVerification: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true)   ,
             getIdToken: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('token')  ,        //mocked here                        
             emailVerified: true 
 }

 export   const user =  { email: 'test@test.com',
                         uid: '12345678abcdefg'
 }
  
 const auth = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  onUserChanged: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(()=>(res:any) => mockedUserCredentials) ,
  onAuthStateChanged: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(()=>(res:any) => user),
   signInWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockedUserCredentials),
   currentUser:mockedUserCredentials,
   
 });
  
   export default auth;

LogniScreen.test.tsx
expect(await authMock.onAuthStateChanged).toBeCalled(); //passed
expect(await authMock.currentUser.getIdToken).toBeCalled();//failed 
  expect(await SecureStore.setItemAsync).toBeCalled(); //failed 
...

I've tried a lot to figure it out but I couldn't make it work ,
i don't know where I'm doing wrong (in onAuthStateChanged mock or getIdToken mock either).
how should I mock them to be able to test the code inside ?.
